# Java subList ConcurrentModificationException();

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sublist

I have got ArrayList defined:

```
ArrayList<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I just want to work wit particular part of it so I have created subList:

```
List<String> numbersh = numbers.subList(o, p + 1);
```

I understand a basic concept and it worked for me till I realized a need to work with ArrayList it self:

```
numbers.remove(p + 1);
```

which works correctly till I try to work with subList again:

```
numbersh.remove(0);
```

I receive /from AbstractList.class/:

```
throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
```

**for better understanding imagine following ArrayList /numbers/:**

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]/numbers/

and its 
`List<String> numbersh = numbersh.subList(3, 5);` which consists from [4,5,6]

and what I'm doing is `numbers.remove(6);` which is out of subList range and should leads to

[1,2,3,4,5,6,8]/numbers/

and then I try to `numbersh.remove(0)` which should lead to:

[1,2,3,5,6,8]/numbers/

I'm kind a lost with this. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post actual code. Human language is too ambiguous.

Comment: @PhilippSander - wrong. look at the code for ArrayList.subList() and you'll see the sublist returned is not a copy.

Comment: "The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list.  (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)" Straight from the JavaDoc. It seems you are doing exactly what the JavaDoc is telling you NOT to do. What exactly are you expecting to happen here?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot that subList() does **not** return new List, but just a portion of original List.

```
public List<E> subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    subListRangeCheck(fromIndex, toIndex, size);
    return new SubList(this, 0, fromIndex, toIndex);
}

SubList(AbstractList<E> parent,
        int offset, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.parentOffset = fromIndex;
    this.offset = offset + fromIndex;
    this.size = toIndex - fromIndex;
    this.modCount = ArrayList.this.modCount;
}
```

If you need to modify and access the List and subList independently you will need to create a deep copy of the original List.